# All rows are one column - PHP created table

Tags: php, html-table, row, echo, multiple-columns

I need to create 3 functions to create a table using PHP.  But I keep getting all data in one row.  It also doesn't look like its the most efficient way to do it.  Can someone tell me what is wrong since it looks like all of the td's are showing up like tr's?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php


function tdFunction1($flavor1, $flavor2, $flavor3)
{
    echo "<td>";
    echo $flavor1;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $flavor2;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $flavor3;
    echo "</td>";
}

function tdFunction2($dessert1, $dessert2, $dessert3)
{
    echo "<td>";
    echo $dessert1;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $dessert2;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $dessert3;
    echo "</td>";
}

function tdFunction3($temp1, $temp2, $temp3)
{
    echo "<td>";
    echo $temp1;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $temp2;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $temp3;
    echo "</td>";
}


echo "<table border=1 style='width:100%;'>";
echo tdFunction1("chocolate", "apple", "vanilla");
echo tdFunction2("Lava Cake", "Cheesecake", "Cream Puffs");
echo tdFunction3("hot", "cold", "cold");
echo "</table>";


?>
</body>
</html>
```

I switched it around to what I have below but I get a 
Fatal error:

> Call to undefined function colFunction1() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trash\index.php on line 39      (the first of my 3 echo colFunction's)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php

function tableFunction()
{
    echo "<table border=1;>";

    function rowFunction()
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        function colFunction1($flavor1, $flavor2, $flavor3)
        {
            echo "<td>".flavor1."</td><td>".flavor2."</td><td>".flavor3."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";


        echo "<tr>";
        function colFunction2($dessert1, $dessert2, $dessert3)
        {
            echo "<td>".dessert1."</td><td>".dessert2."</td><td>".dessert3."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";


        echo "<tr>";
        function colFunction3($temp, $temp2, $temp3)
        {
            echo "<td>".temp1."</td><td>".temp2."</td><td>".temp3."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}

echo colFunction1("chocolate", "apple", "vanilla");
echo colFunction2("Lava Cake", "Cheesecake", "Cream Puffs");
echo colFunction3("hot", "cold", "cold");

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Well I fooled around with it and "think" I figured it out (just in case someone else is as puzzled as I was).
I created a row function to create another row.
I created the column function to take the three function inputs.
Then I created the table to create a table that could be called on its own.
I PRAY I didnt just print out the echos as they are, but I dont think so.  If I am wrong, please someone point it out to me.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php

function trFunction()
{
    echo"<tr>";

    echo"</tr>";
}
function tdFunction($flavor1, $flavor2, $flavor3)
{
    echo"<td>".$flavor1."</td>"; 
    echo"<td>".$flavor2."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$flavor3."</td>";
}
function tableFunction()
{
echo "<table width=400px border=5px cellpadding=3px td style=text-align:center;>";
echo trFunction();
echo tdFunction("Chocolate", "Strawberry","Vanilla" );
echo trFunction();
echo tdFunction("Molten Lava Cake", "Cheesecake", "Cream Puffs");
echo trFunction();
echo tdFunction("Hot","Cold","Cold");
echo "</table>";
}

echo \tableFunction();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a single `<tr>` tag anywhere here! Perhaps that's what's wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Well I fooled around with it and "think" I figured it out (just in case someone else is as puzzled as I was).
I created a row function to create another row.
I created the column function to take the three function inputs.
Then I created the table to create a table that could be called on its own.
I PRAY I didnt just print out the echos as they are, but I dont think so.  If I am wrong, please someone point it out to me.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php

function trFunction()
{
    echo"<tr>";

    echo"</tr>";
}
function tdFunction($flavor1, $flavor2, $flavor3)
{
    echo"<td>".$flavor1."</td>"; 
    echo"<td>".$flavor2."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$flavor3."</td>";
}
function tableFunction()
{
echo "<table width=400px border=5px cellpadding=3px td style=text-align:center;>";
echo trFunction();
echo tdFunction("Chocolate", "Strawberry","Vanilla" );
echo trFunction();
echo tdFunction("Molten Lava Cake", "Cheesecake", "Cream Puffs");
echo trFunction();
echo tdFunction("Hot","Cold","Cold");
echo "</table>";
}

echo \tableFunction();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked well for me. However, do you have the \ for `tableFunction()`? It works with and without it.

Comment: So far as the slash goes, I didnt remember seeing it in any of the tutorials I ran across.  But in using NetBeans, when I typed it in for the echo, it asked me if I wanted it to fix the syntax, soooo I said yes and there it is.

Comment: Ah, well if it works, best to leave well enough alone ;-) Works either way. I +1 btw.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any table rows `echo"<tr><td>".$temp1."</td><td>".$temp2."</td></tr>"`  will give you a 2 column row.

Comment: That gives me the one row with the columns.  But I need 3 functions one to give me the columns that would go inside the function for the rows and all inside the table function (creates the table tags).  I know it doesnt show it but Im trying to start somewhere and this isnt giving me the columns, just rows.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the tags '' (open row) and ' (close row).

A think. You have redundant code. instead of three functions for the same thing you use a function like this:

```
function printRow($val1, $val2, $val3)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$val1.'</td><td>'.$val2.'</td><td>'.$val3.'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}

echo "<table border=1 style='width:100%;'>";
printRow("chocolate", "apple", "vanilla");
// etc.
echo "</table>";
```

or even better in a loop:

```
function printRow($values = array())
{
  $s = '<tr>';

  foreach($values as $value)
  {
    $s.= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';      
  }
  $s.= '</tr>';
  return $s;
}

$valuesToShow[] = array("chocolate", "apple", "vanilla");
$valuesToShow[] = array("Lava Cake", "Cheesecake", "Cream Puffs");
$valuesToShow[] = array("hot", "cold", "cold");

//create table:
echo "<table border=1 style='width:100%;'>";

foreach($valuesToShowas as $value)
{
  echo printRow($value);
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I see all of these will give me a table.  But I have specifics.  I dont want you to give me the complete solution, but a direction would be helpful.  The specifics are:        create a td() function, figure out how to use it and how to create a TR tag with it.  Then, take that idea and make it into your tr() function.  Then, figure out how to use the tr() function to create a full TABLE tag… Lastly, take that idea and put it into a table() function.   Call that table() function from your “main” php code.****Like I said, I dont want the solution, just a direction to how to nest these functions.